# Loop through an array in vlang

Tags: loops, vlang

How can I loop over an array of strings on v programming language?
For example:
`langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']`

Comment: here your answer. https://vlang.io/docs#for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method 1: For loop with index**

```
langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']

for i, lang in langs {
    println('$i) $lang')
}
```

*Method 1 Output:*

```
0) python
1) java
2) javascript
```

Try method 1 on vlang's playground [here](https://vlang.ide.judge0.com/?5LKz)

**Method 2: For loop without index**

```
langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']

for lang in langs {
    println(lang)
}
```

*Method 2 Output:*

```
python
java
javascript
```

Try method 2 on vlang's playground [here](https://vlang.ide.judge0.com/?8nEA)

**Method 3: While loop style iteration using for in V Lang**
You can do this too. Following loop is similar to `while` loop in other languages.

```
mut num := 0
langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']

for{
    if num < langs.len {
        println(langs[num])
    }
    else{
        break
    }
    num++
}
```

*Method 3 Output:*

```
python
java
javascript
```

Try method 3 on vlang's playground [here](https://vlang.ide.judge0.com/?qrZg)

**Method 4: Looping over elements of an array by accessing its index**

```
langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']

mut i := 0
for i < langs.len {
    println(langs[i])
    i++
}
```

*Method 4 Output:*

```
python
java
javascript
```

Try method 4 on V lang's playground [here](https://vlang.ide.judge0.com/?A4v3)

**Method 5: Traditional C-Style looping**

As suggested by @Astariul in the comments

```
langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']

for i := 0; i < langs.len; i++ {
    println(langs[i])
}
```

*Method 5 Output:*

```
python
java
javascript
```

Try method 5 on V lang's playground [here](https://vlang.ide.judge0.com/?yRt8)

You can checkout this playlist for more interesting [vlang tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEPMhdsq-gNpFr40A-ZnX-Hu9l-Sp5Oc_)

Comment: Note : you can also use a C-style loop (looping over the indexes of the array)

Comment: @Astariul, added it as method 4. Hope that is what you're suggesting for

Comment: I was more thinking of the loop where i is declared inside the loop (`for i := 0; i < langs.len; i++`), as described in the [documentation of V](https://vlang.io/docs#for). But this one works too ^^
Thanks for keeping the answer updated :)

Comment: Nicer then is: for i in 0..langs.len

Answer (score 1):

V has only one looping construct: `for`.
In order to loop over the array `langs`, you need to use the for loop.

```
langs := ['python', 'java', 'javascript']
for lang in langs {
    println(lang)
}
```

The for value in loop is used for going through elements of an array. If an index is required, an alternative form `for index, value in` can be used.